# MySQL query from JSON datatype column that has backslash character

Tags: mysql, json

I have a difficulty to query element in JSON column in MySQL

This is my data :
[image]

example of whats in the column :
`{\order\":[{\"product_id\":3,\"quantity\":5,\"product_name\":\"Ikan salmon bakar \"}]}"`

I'm using this sql syntax  :

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(order_list, '$.order[*].product_id') FROM orders_copy WHERE id = 3;`

If I use this query to the column that contain backslash, then it will produce null.

[image]

Expected result (eg:) :

[image]

I'm not sure if I should get rid of the backslash so that the query will produce result or is there any effective way solving it ?.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65045564/edit) and input the example table data in textual form instead of image? It will be much easier to do copy-paste and reproduce your situation.

Comment: hi @tcadidot0, i have already put the data into text form below the table :). I just take one . is it okay?

Comment: Hi Syahirah, please look at this updated fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef8d2c833a989cc862fe064c70cf5aa6

Comment: Are you using MariaDB?

Comment: var json_obj = $.parseJSON(order_list);

Comment: @tcadidot0 your solution worked well. but i think its my data problem because the data comes from the app are with backslash and even i move it to the new table and query it, the backslash still there an d it returns null .. yes I'm using mariadb

Comment: @KashifSolangi if i'm using mysql, does it will work?

Comment: I think there's a workaround for that if you don't want to update all the backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answers for problem I stated above.

It is just that I found the answer through this link : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace , where I search for what are the code that are compatible with MySQL version to cater special character. For backslash, I'm using JSON_UNQUOTE()

Here I put the solution : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i7EpX4Qq86iJWFkPgzMhVX/0

Thanks to those who help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the backslash using `REPLACE()` and make the main query to become a sub-query before the `JSON_EXTRACT` function take place. Try this query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(od, '$.order[*].product_id') 
FROM 
(SELECT *, REPLACE(order_list,'\\','') AS od FROM orders_copy WHERE id = 3) A;
```

And here's an example fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=6f52caffa6c97bbcfcc18bb5fb713348

Comment: It seems that I'm bit confused with the mariadb thingy, coz actually it still does not work in my platform. I'm using MySQL db Forge Studio. But I think what u give is right, it just that me that don't know even I'm on maria db or not

Comment: I think i'm using 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: Oh yea.. I can see that.. its like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mbfCY7cuEJfAwhndJBXGGZ/0

Comment: yup, thats right . the output is null . So is it the difference server that cause this problem?